# How to convert UTC/extended format to datetime in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I want to convert datetime in `%Y-%m-%d`,
so from `Sat, 17 Apr 2021 16:17:00 +0100` to `17-04-2021`

```
def convertDatetime(data):
    test_datetime = data
    data_new_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(test_datetime,'%- %Y %M %d')
    print(data_new_format)

convertDatetime("Sat, 17 Apr 2021 16:17:00 +0100")
```

but it say me: `'-' is a bad directive in format '%- %Y %M %d'`

Comment: by the way, the format you have is "RFC1123", as described in [RFC1123](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format you specify `'%- %Y %M %d'` (1) contains an incorrect specifier `-` as the error says, and also (2) *completely does not match* the data you want to convert. The format you pass to `strptime()` must match the way the data looks, not the way you want it to look.

```
>>> data="Sat, 17 Apr 2021 16:17:00 +0100"
>>> format = "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(data, format)
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 17, 16, 17, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)))
```

To reformat the datetime the way you want, you need a second call, to `strftime()`:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(data, format).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2021-04-17'
```

Comment: (3) the input isn't UTC either, but 1 hour ahead (+0100).

Comment: @MrFuppes One must not expect terminological exactitude from beginners. I don't know what OP meant by putting UTC in the header and I'm not sure he does. So I just ignored that bit and concentrated on the primary confusion between a string representation of a date and a `datetime`.